# how to compare two columns in pandas to make a third column ?

Tags: python, pandas

i have two columns age and sex in a pandas dataframe

```
sex = ['m', 'f' , 'm', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f']
age = [16 ,  15 , 14 , 9  , 8   , 2   , 56 ]
```

now i want to extract a third column : like this 
if age <=9 then output ' child' and if age >9 then output the respective gender

```
sex = ['m', 'f'  , 'm','f'    ,'f'    ,'f'    , 'f']
age = [16 ,  15  , 14 , 9     , 8     , 2     , 56 ]
yes = ['m', 'f'  ,'m' ,'child','child','child','f' ]
```

please help 
ps . i am still working on it if i get anything  i will immediately update

Answer (score 19):

Use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['col3'] = np.where(df['age'] <= 9, 'child', df['sex'])
```

The resulting output:

```
   age sex   col3
0   16   m      m
1   15   f      f
2   14   m      m
3    9   f  child
4    8   f  child
5    2   f  child
6   56   f      f
```

**Timings**

Using the following setup to get a larger sample DataFrame:

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
n = 10**5
df = pd.DataFrame({'sex': np.random.choice(['m', 'f'], size=n), 'age': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=n)})
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit np.where(df['age'] <= 9, 'child', df['sex'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop

%timeit df['sex'].where(df['age'] > 9, 'child')
100 loops, best of 3: 3.25 ms per loop

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: 'child' if x['age'] <= 9 else x['sex'], axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.92 ms per loop
```

Comment: is this working like this np.where( condition , if do this , else do this ) ?

Comment: yup this seems very okay to use , although df.apply looks very intuitive :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use [pandas.DataFrame.where](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html). For example

```
child.where(age<=9, sex)
```

Comment: The syntax here is incorrect.  If you want to use `DataFrame.where`, it should be something like: `df['sex'].where(df['age'] > 9, 'child')`.

Answer (score 5):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sex':['m', 'f' , 'm', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f'],
    'age':[16, 15, 14, 9, 8, 2, 56]})
df['yes'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'child' if x['age'] <= 9 else x['sex'], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   age sex    yes
0   16   m      m
1   15   f      f
2   14   m      m
3    9   f  child
4    8   f  child
5    2   f  child
6   56   f      f
```