# Pandas: Insert New column to dataframe and populate values within new column based on if then logic

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two country descriptions. Sometimes they match, sometimes they don't.

```
Country Desc1        Country Desc2

1    US           US  
2    US           UK           
3    UK           US    
4    UK           UK
```

I need to 1.) insert another column (Country Desc3) with all the row values populated with 2.) a rule that returns Country Desc1 if it matches Country Desc2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to compare two columns in pandas to make a third column ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925082/how-to-compare-two-columns-in-pandas-to-make-a-third-column)

Comment: If you need `NaN` I will recommend Both @piRSquared 's and @Rayhane Mama's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Country Desc3'] = \
    df['Country Desc1'].mask(df['Country Desc1'] != df['Country Desc2'])

df

  Country Desc1 Country Desc2 Country Desc3
0            US            US            US
1            US            UK           NaN
2            UK            US           NaN
3            UK            UK            UK
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `iloc` and `join`:

```
df['Country Desc3'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] if x.iloc[0] == x.iloc[1] else ', '.join(x),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Country Desc1 Country Desc2 Country Desc3
1            US            US            US
2            US            UK        US, UK
3            UK            US        UK, US
4            UK            UK            UK
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as follows:

```
df['Country Desc3'] = np.where(df['Country Desc1']==df['Country Desc2'],df['Country Desc1'],np.nan)
```

this will give you:

```
  Country Desc1 Country Desc2 Country Desc3
1            US            US            US
2            US            US            US
3            UK            US           NaN
4            UK            UK            UK
```

if you don't like to have `NaN` values just change `np.nan` by whatever you like, for example : `df['Country Desc1']+', '+df['Country Desc2']` to have the concat of the two columns when they don't match.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , if you need a string in new column

```
df['Country Desc3']=df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique().tolist()), axis=1)
```

If you need a list in new column

```
df['Country Desc3']=df.apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist(), axis=1)
```

Just in case you need `NaN` for no matched row

```
df['Country Desc3']=np.nan
df.loc[df['Country Desc1']==df['Country Desc2'],'Country Desc3']=df['Country Desc1']
```