# Pandas TypeError: data type '' not understood

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read two csv files and compare two columns with each other whether there are same entries or not.

However for some reason I can not compare them due to the following issue: 
TypeError: data type '' not understood.

I have tried the following things to solve this problem:

```
df_1['Vendor Number'].replace('', np.NAN, inplace=True)
df_1['Vendor Number'].replace('"', '', inplace=True)
df_1['Vendor Number'].dropna(inplace=True)

df_2['Artikel_Nummer'].replace('', np.NAN, inplace=True)
df_2['Artikel_Nummer'].replace('"', '', inplace=True)
df_2['Artikel_Nummer'].dropna(inplace=True)
```

But none of it worked does anyone have an idea how i can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Is it not better to merge the vendor CSV's and then compare by 'Artikel_Nummer' and 'Vendor Number'? As for your question, maybe you can strip with `rstrip('.!? \n\t')` to get rid of any characters which may cause problems.

Comment: So I merged the two df's, now I'm trying to create a new column with the result in it like this: df['Result'] = df[df['Artikel_Nummer'] == df['Vendor Number']] but that gives me the error: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Comment: You could do the following with NumPy: 

df['result'] = np.where(df['Artikel_Nummer'] == df["Vendor Number"], 'same', 'Not same'')

Did not test it though..

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925082/how-to-compare-two-columns-in-pandas-to-make-a-third-column